# Postgres timestamp difference seem to miss 1 hour?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to calculate difference between two dates in postgres and found out that on several cases my tests fail, while debugging I found an interesting thing - when I subtract one date from another it seems to lack one hour, here's the script (table has only one timestamp field):

```
select now(), d1, now() - d1, extract(day from date_trunc('day', now() - d1))
from test;
```

And here's the result:
[image]

This seemed strange, so I decided to check it with some other service and got the result I expected (23 hrs instead of 22):

[image]
(see https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=2&m1=3&y1=2019&d2=1&m2=4&y2=2019&h1=23&i1=55&s1=00&h2=23&i2=48&s2=30).

Can somebody explain these results? Am I doing something wrong or missing something obvious? I'm using Postgres 9.6 on macOS.

Comment: Sounds like a day-lights-savings-time issue.

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: it's Ukraine, yes guys, I completely missed that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Many countries switch to daylight savings time between March 2nd and April 1st](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html). Because the clocks move ahead there is one less hour between 2.March.2019 and 1.April.2019.

Beware that Postgres has its own time zone which may not match the user's time zone, especially for a web application. To deal with this, set the application to the user's time zone and the database to UTC. Translate all dates to UTC before passing them to the database.